# add key before value in dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I want to add the key before I add the value. The code in the current stage it does the opposite..

```
enter def px():
for i in x:
    print(i, "equal" , x[i] )

x = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3, "d" : 4}

px()

x[input("Add a letter ")] = input("Add a number ")

px() here
```

Anybody able to help?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You put a key, value pair in a dictionary.  And that looks like what your code is doing.  What do you mean to add the key first, and what do you mean it is doing the opposite?

Comment: I want it to ask for the key first, not the value

Comment: well, I'd answer it, but Scott Hunter beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ask for the key, then ask for the value, THEN make the entry in the dictionary: 3 separate steps:

```
k = input("Add a letter ")
v = input("Add a number ")
x[k] = v
```